# Is there distributed fuzz testing platform against modern proprietary CPU like SETI@HOME?

Tags: fuzzing

My idea is near what SETI Institute does.

Distributed [fuzz testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz%5ftesting) against modern **Intel** and **Amd** Central processing units(CPU).

To find similar to [Blue Pill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue%5fPill%5f%28software%29) bugs.

Is there?

Comment: I don't think you're going to find anything in a CPU like those ones using fuzzing. But, good luck!